# MVC Passing ViewModel to @Html.Partial

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, partial-views

Passing ViewModel to @Html.Partial

Have two ViewModels

```
public class RegisterVM
{
  ... some properties
  public AddressVM AddressInformation { get; set; } //viewmodel
}

public class AddressVM {
   public string Street1 { get; set; }
   public string Street2 { get; set; }
   public string PostalCode { get; set; }
}
```

When loading main view using VM:

```
    @model ViewModels.RegisterVM
```

All field load. But When I add Partial View and pass viewmodel

```
     @Html.Partial("_AddressDetails", Model.AddressInformation)
```

It fails
Error: Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Why does it fail?

The partial View _AddressDetails is expecting a

```
         @model ViewModels.AddressVM
```

**Update**

Based on changes from Prashant,

When submitting the information The Address information is NULL. 
In The controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterVM vm){
     ...
    //when viewing vm.AddressInformation.Street1 is null. and there is a value
    //Is there a different way of retrieving the values from partial view?
    }
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Are you sure that you instantiate the Model and Model.AddressInformation?

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin what you mean instantiate the Model? In the Controller I just have  public ActionResult Register(){  return View();  } and all fields/textboxes load without exception if I comment the Html.Partial line

Comment: You pass the `null` value as a model, that's why you get NullReference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is generated because property `AddressInformation` is null, and you need to initailize it in a parameterless constructor or in the controller before you pass it to the view, for example

```
public class RegisterVM
{
  public RegisterVM() // default constructor
  {
    AddressInformation = new AddressVM();
  }
  public AddressVM AddressInformation { get; set; }
  ....
}
```

However you usage means that the controls generated will be

```
<input name="Street1" .../>
```

whereas they need to be

```
<input name="AddressInformation.Street1" .../>
```

in order to bind to your model. You can either make your partial an `EditorTemplate` (`/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/AddressVM.cshtml`) and use in the main view as

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.AddressInformation)
```

or pass the prefix to the partial as additional `ViewData`

```
@Html.Partial("_AddressDetails", Model.AddressInformation, new ViewDataDictionary { TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = "AddressInformation" }})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me. You just need to instantiate your VM, attach it and send it to the view.

**Page Action**

```
public ActionResult Page(){
     RegisterVM vm = new RegisterVM();
     vm.AddressInformation = new AddressVM();
     return View(vm);
}
```

**Page.cshtml**

```
@model Project.Web.Models.RegisterVM
<!-- loading partial view -->
@Html.Partial("_AddressDetails",Model.AddressInformation)
```

**Partial View File**

```
<input type="text" name="name" value=" " />
```

Comment: A working solution. That partial view example is a bit confusing though (normally html, head and body are not really part of a partial). Also it's missing @model AddressVM

Comment: Can you please explain why you instantiate the model in the controller? I want to understand because if I dont call partial view then I dont need to instantiate the model?

Comment: @Ben because `Model` an object, and `Model.AddressInformation` is also an object which is null since its not instantiated anywhere. Either you need to pass it like i did or you need to do replace your code : `@Html.Partial("_AddressDetails", Model.AddressInformation)` with `@Html.Partial("_AddressDetails", new AddressInformation());`

Comment: Personally I would use the controller to instantiate the viewmodel (like PrashantGhimire did), and have a constructor instantiate the sub classes/objects (e.g. AdressInformation). The results are the same though. @Ben if you don't want/need to pass a model, you don't have to. But you can't tell the view to require a model (@model xyz) and then not supply it. It can be empty though.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.@PrashantGhimire Can you please see my updated question. The registration form loads but I cant retrieving the values.. is there a different way of retrieving the values from the partial view

Answer (score 0):

I am not having more info about code but as per mention details, can you try this
public ActionResult Register(){ return View(**register**); }

i know you may tried this but try to assigned explict value. as this is basic MVC implementation. if it not work out then you need to provide more code details.

hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

in Register get Method must instatiate your viewModel because in view, call other partial with viewModel members(proprties);

```
public ActionResult Register(){
 RegisterVM vm = new RegisterVM();
 return View(vm);
}
```